# Fabricjs Failed to execute 'texImage2D' on 'WebGLRenderingContext': The image element contains cross-origin data, and may not be loaded

Tags: reactjs, fabricjs

I'm using Amazon S3 and cloud front. The image url look like https://t.pimg.jp/061/089/535/2/61089535.jpg

My code look like

```
const imgUrl = 'https://t.pimg.jp/061/089/535/2/61089535.jpg';
fabric.util.loadImage(imgUrl, function(imgObj) {
    const oImg = new fabric.Image(imgObj, {
        crossOrigin: 'anonymous',
    });

    ...
});
```

The image loaded successfully. But when I apply filter to that image, the error appears.

Already applied the cors config at s3 bucket

```
<CORSConfiguration>
 <CORSRule>
   <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
   <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
   <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
 </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Do anyone know how to fix?

Answer (score 6):

1. If you want to use [`util.loadImage()`](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.util.html#.loadImage), you should supply it the
   `crossOrigin` parameter. In your code you're setting the
   `crossOrigin: 'anonymous'` in the callback - the image is already
   downloaded with the wrong CORS policy by that time.
2. The image in your question doesn't actually have
   `access-control-allow-origin` header set, at least not at the time of my
   writing. So I've used a different image as an example:

```js
const canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c')
const imgUrl = 'https://c1.staticflickr.com/9/8873/18598400202_3af67ef38f_q.jpg'

fabric.util.loadImage(imgUrl, (imgObj) => {
    const img = new fabric.Image(imgObj)
    img.filters.push(new fabric.Image.filters.Grayscale())
    img.applyFilters()
    canvas.add(img)
}, null, 'anonymous')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/3.6.2/fabric.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" width="300" height="200"></canvas>
```

I'd also suggest using [`fabric.Image.fromURL()`](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Image.html#.fromURL) - it's a cleaner way to load an image:

```
fabric.Image.fromURL(imgUrl, (img) => {
    img.filters.push(new fabric.Image.filters.Grayscale())
    img.applyFilters()
    canvas.add(img)
}, {crossOrigin: 'anonymous'})
```